# Match and use match with regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I have never used regular expressions in javascript and the time has come, I think.

I need to search `window.location` and see if it has a parameter I need - `start=SOME_NUMBER`.
If the search returns true, I need to have `start=SOME_NUMBER` to bt returned to me and store it in a variable.

The good thing is, I can create the pattern myself, but the bad thing is that I have no idea how to write the code in javascript. So, I basically don't know where and how to use my pattern.

If someone could give me a brief explanation on how javascript works with regex, I'd be really thankful.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Also, if the pattern doesn't match anything, I'd want the variable to return empty.

Comment: What about the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `string.match(regexp)` function. I have a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/E7frT/.

```
var matches = window.location.toString().match(/[^\w]start=(\d+)/i);
// above we are using a case insensitive regexp with numbers as a matching group
// indicated with the parenthesis, this makes it possible to extract that part of
// the match

var start = null;
if(matches) {
  start = matches[1];
  // The matches will be an array if there were any, the zero index will contain
  // the entire match index one onward will be any matching groups in our regexp

}
// start will be null if no match or the number (as a string) if there is a match
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular-Expressions.info has a great [Javascript breakdown](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html).  When combined with its [Flavor comparison](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html), you can pretty much write anything you need.  Enjoy!

Comment: Good advice, but not an answer to the specific problem.

Comment: @Barmar On the contrary, it's the answer to the exact question OP asked: "If someone could give me a brief explanation on how javascript works with regex, I'd be really thankful."  I've done exactly that :c)

Comment: OK, if we're going to be pedantic, that's a statement about his state of mind, not a question.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not being pedantic at all!  OP gave a problem statement, but made it very clear that he was perfectly capable in both JS and RegEx, and wanted merely to know how the two worked together.  I think I've answered the question more succinctly than the other submissions, and I've fostered real learning by giving OP a reference rather than a line of code.  "Give a man a fish", right?

Answer (score 0):

You can look for the "start=NUMBER" with

```
String(window.location).match(/start=[0-9]+/g);
```

It will return the whole "start=NUMBER", but it shouldn't be hard to filter the number there.